# Matlab: how to convert character array or string into a formatted output OR parse a string

Tags: matlab, cell

Could someone please tell me how to convert character array into a formatted output using Matlab?

I am expecting data like this:

```
 CHAR (1 x 29) : 0.050822999    3.141592979 ; (1)
```

OR

```
CELL (1 x 1) or string: '0.050822999       3.141592979  ; (1)'
```

I am looking for output like this:

```
 d1 = 0.050822999; %double
 d2 = 3.141592979; %double
 index    = 1;   % integer
```

I tried transposing and then using str2num(Str'); but, it's returning me 0x 0 double.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
DK

Comment: Please provide an example character array for those example outputs... or are those inputs? If they are then rather than saying `CELL (1 x 1) : ...` it might be clearer to say `Str = {'0.050822999 3.141592979}` and then providing the formatted output that you expect

Comment: What is the input you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to parse the string

```
c = { '0.050822999 3.141592979 ; (1)' };
p = regexp( c{1}, '^(\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)\s*;\s*\((\d+)\)$', 'tokens', 'once' ); %//parse the input string
numbers = str2mat(p); %// convert extracted strings to numerical values
```

Example result

```
ans =
0.050822999
3.141592979
1
```

---

Explaining the `regexp` pattern:

- `^` - pattern starts at the beginning of the input string
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - parentheses (`'()'`) enclosing this sub-pattern indicates it as a single token
  `\d+` matches one or more digits, then expecting `\.` a dot (notice the `\`, since `.` alone in regexp acts as a wildcard) and after the dot `\d+` one or more digits are expected.
  This token should correspond to the first number, e.g., `0.050822999`
- `\s` expecting a single space
- `(\d+\.\d+)` - again, expecting another decimal fraction as the second token.
- `\s*` - expecting white space (zero or more).
- `;` - capture the `;` in the expression, but not as a token.
- `\s+` - expecting white space (zero or more).
- `\(` - expecting an open parenthesis, note the `\` since parentheses in regexp are used to denote tokens.
- `(\d+)` - expecting one or more digits as the third token, only integer numbers are expected here. no decimal point.
- `\)` - expecting a closing parenthesis.
- `$` - pattern should reach the end of the input string.

Comment: Thanks. that worked. Could you please ALSO explain the pattern in regexp?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this (if I understood you correctly)

```
function str_dump(var)
  info = whos;
  disp([info.class ' ' mat2str(info.size) ' : ' var]);
end
```

This just shows information about the string. If you want to parse it and convert to another Matlab's structure, you have to explain it more carefully.

Comment: If it is possible to avoid the usage of `eval` one should do so, because it is a horror to debug.

Comment: that is much better :)

Answer (score 2):

```
%// Input
a = [0.050822999 3.141592979];
n = 1;

%// Output
str = [num2str(a,'%0.9f   ') ' ; (' num2str(n) ')']
```

Result:

```
str =
0.050822999   3.141592979 ; (1)
```